# passing object in State() in react

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React State. Here I am dynamically changing the value of  according to user input  using State().

```
import React from "react";

function App() {
  var [fullName, setFullName] = React.useState({
    fName: "",
    lName: ""
  });
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>
        Hello {fullName.fName} {fullName.lName}
        {/* {console.log(fullName)} */}
      </h1>
      <form>
/*//////////////////////////////////////////this below is correct segment and works*/

        {/* <input
          onChange={(event) => {
            setFullName({ fName: event.target.value, lName: fullName.lName });
          }}
          name="fName"
          placeholder="First Name"
        />
        <input
          onChange={(event) => {
            setFullName({ fName: fullName.fName, lName: event.target.value });
          }}
          name="lName"
          placeholder="Last Name"
        /> */}
/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
```

Here **setFullName** seems to be taking an object as parameter, so why is the code not working when i update the value of  **fullName**(object) and passing it into **setFullName**???

```
        <input
          onChange={(event) => {
            fullName.fName = event.target.value;

            setFullName(fullName);
          }}
          name="fName"
          placeholder="First Name"
        />
        <input
          onChange={(event) => {
            fullName.lName = event.target.value;
            setFullName(fullName);
          }}
          name="lName"
          placeholder="Last Name"
        />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Does the input has to be a object declared inside State ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't mutate the state object directly. The fact that you are setting the `fullName` state object is wrong. Instead try something like this;

```
onChange={(event) => {
                      const tempState = {...fullName}
                      tempState.lName = event.target.value;
                      setFullName(tempState)
          }}
```

The difference here is, I created a copy of the current state, then mutated the copy object (thus didn't directly mutate the state object which is a hard NO in react) and then set the state accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because you are trying to mutate the state directly. This is not allowed.

```
        onChange={(event) => {
           //Get the current state, shallow copy it and then override the property with your new value
            setFullName(prevState => ({
                 ...prevState,
                 lName: event.target.value
                 }));
          }}
```

Answer (score 1):

React doesn't allow you to directly update the state value. Here's why [outsite link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40309023/13150380)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as you are expecting an object in useState then you can only assign an object of type

`{fName: "abc", lName: "xyz"}`

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to attach a name handler to the input tag and grab it using event.name to update the state. As others stated, you can't mutate state directly, you have to update it like this.

```
const [fullName, setFullName] = useState({ fName: "", lName: "" })

const handleChange = e => {
  setFullName({ 
    ...fullName,
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  })
}

<input 
  name="fName" 
  placeholder="First Name" 
  onChange={handleChange}
/>

<input 
  name="lName" 
  placeholder="Last Name" 
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```